# jquery how to fadeout objects simultaneously

Tags: jquery, fadeout

I am trying to fadeOut a few objects at the same time, here is my code:

```
$("#close-case-study").click(function() {
$("#case-study-btns").fadeOut(500);
$("[id$='-discover']").fadeOut(500);
```

});

The problem is they are not in sync one starts then the other follows a split second after. What am I doing wrong? Is it because the second selector is looking for more than one item with the id ending in -discover?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#close-case-study").click(function() {
$("#case-study-btns, [id$='-discover']").fadeOut(500);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this would help:

```
 $("#case-study-btns, [id$='-discover']").fadeOut(500);
```